# Pausing a sprite kit game and transitioning to home menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, save, sprite-kit, transition

I am developing a game in Xcode's sprite kit that I intend on shipping to the AppStore. I have a gameplay scene where all of the objects are SKSpriteNodes and are children of a single SKNode *nodePlay. One of these is a button that pauses the game and brings up a custom pause menu. In the pause menu, the user can resume, restart, go to settings, go to main menu, et cetera. An important feature I want to retain is the state of the game when we pause it, such as the level/timers/ position of objects executing SKActions.

I have found several ways to do this but I wanted to ask frankly if there is a 'best'/preferred method and why . Here are just a few that I came up with myself/ across research:

1) Use two view controllers. The first runs only the gameplay scene, and the pause button transitions the user to the second view controller, where the other SKScenes will appear (settings scene, home scene, ...). This way when I set nodePlay.paused=true on the first view controller and transition to the second view controller by poping, the state of my first view controller will be kept (including suspension of any SKActions) when I pop back.

2) Combine the play SKScene and the pause SKScene as a single SKScene so when we pause the game, the current view will just bring up an SKNode *nodePause with several SKSpriteNode/SKLabelNode children that act as the buttons (I'll set nodePlay.paused=true and set alpha to 0.5 and zposition=-10 so it is clearly in the background).

3) Archive the gameplay SKScene and transition between scenes with something like:

```
SKScene *pauseScene = [[MyPauseScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
[self.view presentScene:pauseScene];
```

and if we resume, we will restore the archived scene. A major issue I have read on this is that it does not save the state of SKActions (if I have moveBy, it will move objects not as desired or if I have moveTo over duration, the object will be moved very slowly...)

If there is a better way that I haven't listed I'd really appreciate the advice - thanks!

Comment: 1 won't work cause you can have only one active skview, 3 is overkill and problematic, 2 is what is usually done